# Programmatically modify a fact slot using ClipsPy

Tags: python, clips, clipspy

How to modify a fact of a template in CLIPS using ClipsPy.

I have tried the reassigning slot value and sending modify in `clips.build` routine, (see `py_modify` function below) which did not work.

This is the .clp file

```
;; KB.clp
(deftemplate t
    (slot s_1 (type SYMBOL)))

(defrule main-intent
    (initial-fact)
    =>
    (assert (t (s_1 v_1)))
)

(defrule rule_1
    ?p<-(t (s_1 ?v))
    =>
    (printout t"BEFORE"crlf) (py_pfact)
    (py_modify ?p)
    (printout t"AFTER"crlf) (py_pfact)
)
```

This is the python file..

```
# run.py
import clips

clips_env = clips.Environment()

def py_pfact():
    for fact in clips_env.facts():
        print(fact)

def py_modify(p):
    print("--modifying",p["s_1"])
    p["s_1"] = "v_2"  # Try 1
    clips.build("(modify "+str(p.index)+ " (s_1 v_2)") #Try 2

clips_env.define_function(py_pfact)
clips_env.define_function(py_modify)

clips_env.load("KB.clp")
clips_env.reset()
clips_env.run()
```

The ouput is

```
 BEFORE
(initial-fact)
(t (s_1 v_1))
--modifying v_1
AFTER
(initial-fact)
(t (s_1 v_1))
```

I expect `s_1` slot to be modified to `v_2` from `v_1`, but it is not.

Comment: It is not necessary to add the initial-fact to a rule with no other conditions; it is added automatically in versions of CLIPS prior to version 6.3. The initial-fact functionality was deprecated in the 6.3 release; it is still asserted by a reset, but rules without conditions no longer rely on it. In the 6.4 release, the initial-fact is no longer asserted, so rules that explicitly match this fact will no longer be activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`environment.build`](https://clipspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#defining-clips-constructs) method is for building constructs (`defrule`, `deftemplate`, etc.) within the engine. To execute CLIPS code, you need to use [`environment.eval`](https://clipspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#evaluating-clips-code).

In CLIPS 6.30 it's not possible to change a fact once asserted (6.40 added APIs for that). Only way to do so is by retracting the old one and asserting a new one with updated values.

```
def modify_fact(fact):
    """Modify a template fact."""
    fact.retract()

    new_fact = fact.template.new_fact()
    new_fact.update(dict(fact))  # copy over old fact slot values

    new_fact["s_1"] = clips.Symbol("v_2") 

    new_fact.assertit()
```

CLIPS provides the `modify` command which does the exact same: retracts the fact and asserts it with the new value. Nevertheless, it cannot be used via `environment.eval` as fact indexes cannot be used via the API. If you want to modify a fact within a rule, you'd better use the `modify` command directly.

```
(defrule rule_1
  ?p <- (t (s_1 ?v))
  =>
  (modify ?p (s_1 v_2)))
```

Comment: Can we send a root level command using clipsPy? Something like SendCommand, because Eval raises an error if I send a modify statement in it.

Comment: `clipspy` does not support such feature. It makes little sense to eval CLIPS commands in Python when you can simply execute them natively within the rules. The `eval` method should be really used in corner cases as it is quite slow.

Comment: For my use case, I need to analyse user input to decide which slot of template needs to be modified/asserted/retracted or to handle some special cases. Not sure but may be SendCommand would have been helpful for special cases. (I'm still learning clips. I have experimented with PyCLIPS which supports both Eval and SendCommand)

Comment: I'd recommend you to explain what you are trying to achieve in a more broad question then. State what are you trying to do. What have you done so far and what is the challenge you are facing.

Comment: You can also use the CLIPS forum for open ended questions and recommendations.

Comment: Sure. Btw It is briefly explained [here](http://pyclips.sourceforge.net/web/?q=node/13) that some actions behave differently when evaluated and hence the SendCommand in PYCLIPS. I don't know which are these actions and if I will need to use them in future. However if you can confirm such an issue will not come up in CLIPSPY  It'll save me some time.