# Irregularity in modifying a slot value in a CLIPS fact template using clipsPy

Tags: python, clips, clipspy

I am trying to modify a fact template from python using CLIPSPY. It behaves strangely as it does modify a slot for the first time, but then for next slot, it does not and even re-modify the previous modified slot value to something else itself!!

This is the python file.

```
# run.py
import clips

clips_env = clips.Environment()

def py_modify_s1(p):
    p.retract()
    p["s_1"] = clips.Symbol("ABC") 
    p.assertit()

def py_modify_s2(p):
    p.retract()
    p["s_2"] = clips.Symbol("DEF") 
    p.assertit()

clips_env.define_function(py_modify_s1)
clips_env.define_function(py_modify_s2)

clips_env.load("KB.clp")
clips_env.reset()
clips_env.run()
```

This is the clp file.

```
(deftemplate t
        (slot s_1 (type SYMBOL) (default none))
        (slot s_2 (type SYMBOL) (default none))
)

(defrule rule_0
        (initial-fact)
        =>
        (assert (t))
)

(defrule rule_1
        ?p<-(t  (s_1 none) (s_2 none))
        =>
        (py_modify_s1 ?p)
        (facts)
)

(defrule rule_2
        ?p <- (t (s_1 ?x&~none) (s_2 none))
        =>
        (py_modify_s2 ?p)
        (facts)
)

(defrule rule_3
        ?p <- (t (s_1 ?x&~none) (s_2 ?y&~none))
        =>
        (printout t "All set")
        (facts)
)
```

Running the same clip file in CLIPS shell (replacing py_modify with `(modify ?p (s_1,ABC))`) produces expected result. But running from clipspy I get:

```
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-2     (t (s_1 ABC) (s_2 none))
For a total of 2 facts.
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-2     (t (s_1 ▒▒▒3wU) (s_2 none))
For a total of 2 facts.
```

Notice how `s_1` is containing some garbage value after firing of `rule_2` and `s_2` is not modified only. As a result, `rule_3` never gets fired.

Comment: Updated the [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967519/how-to-modify-a-fact-in-a-template-using-clipspy) with the latest findings.

Comment: It is not necessary to add the initial-fact to a rule with no other conditions; it is added automatically in versions of CLIPS prior to version 6.3. The initial-fact functionality was deprecated in the 6.3 release; it is still asserted by a reset, but rules without conditions no longer rely on it. In the 6.4 release, the initial-fact is no longer asserted, so rules that explicitly match this fact will no longer be activated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out facts cannot be modified once asserted via the C (and therefore Python) API. Only way to change a fact is retract the original one and assert a new one. Chapter `4.4.22 EnvPutFactSlot` of the Advanced Programming Guide.

The only way possible seems to be retracting the old fact and asserting a new one with updated values.

```
def modify_fact(fact):
    """Modify a template fact."""
    fact.retract()

    new_fact = fact.template.new_fact()
    new_fact.update(dict(fact))  # copy over old fact slot values

    new_fact["s_1"] = clips.Symbol("v_2") 

    new_fact.assertit()
```

I raised this issue in a [discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/clipsrules/discussion/776946/thread/1741caf1ad/#4930) on the CLIPS forum as well.